# Drop the duplicated rows and merge the ids using groupby in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe where some of rows having duplicated `ids` but different `timestamp` and some of rows having duplicated `ids` but the same `timestamp` but having one of following (`yob` and `gender`) columns null. Now I want to do an operation using groupby:

1. if the same `id` having difference `timestamp`, want to pickup the recent timestamp.
2. If the same `ids` having same `timestamp` but the any of column having null(`yob` and `gender`), that time, want to merge the both `id` as single record without null. below I have pasted the data frame and desired output.

Input data

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("e5882", "null", "M", "AD", "9/14/2021 13:50"),
    ("e5882", "null", "M", "AD", "10/22/2021 13:10"),
    ("5cddf", "null", "M", "ED", "9/9/2021 12:00"),
    ("5cddf", "2010", "null", "ED", "9/9/2021 12:00"),
    ("c3882", "null", "M", "BD", "11/27/2021 5:00"), 
    ("c3882", "1975", "null",  "BD", "11/27/2021 5:00"),
    ("9297d","1999", "null", "GF","10/18/2021 7:00"),
    ("9298e","1990","null","GF","10/18/2021 7:00")
]).toDF(["ID", "yob", "gender","country","timestamp"])
```

[image]

Desire output:

[image]

code used in this problem, but not get the accurate result, some of `ids` are missing,

```
w = Window.partitionBy('Id')
# to obtain the recent date 
df1 = df.withColumn('maxB', F.max('timestamp').over(w)).where(F.col('timestamp') == F.col('maxB')).drop('maxB')
# to merge the null column based of id  
(df1.groupBy('Id').agg(*[F.first(x,ignorenulls=True) for x in df1.columns if x!='Id'])).show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this input dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("e5882", None, "M", "AD", "9/14/2021 13:50"),
    ("e5882", None, "M", "AD", "10/22/2021 13:10"),
    ("5cddf", None, "M", "ED", "9/9/2021 12:00"),
    ("5cddf", "2010", None, "ED", "9/9/2021 12:00"),
    ("c3882", None, "M", "BD", "11/27/2021 5:00"),
    ("c3882", "1975", None, "BD", "11/27/2021 5:00"),
    ("9297d", None, "M", "GF", "10/18/2021 7:00"),
    ("9297d", "1999", None, "GF", "10/18/2021 7:00"),
    ("9298e", "1990", None, "GF", "10/18/2021 7:00"),
], ["id", "yob", "gender", "country", "timestamp"])
```

> 1. If the same `id` having difference `timestamp`, want to pickup the recent timestamp.

Use window ranking function to get most recent row per `id`. As you want to merge those with the same timestamp you can use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`. But first you need to convert `timestamp` strings into TimestampType otherwise comparison won't be correct (as `'9/9/2021 12:00' > '10/18/2021 7:00'`)

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_most_recent = df.withColumn(
   "timestamp",
   F.to_timestamp("timestamp", "M/d/yyyy H:mm")
).withColumn(
   "rn",
   F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.desc("timestamp")))
).filter("rn = 1")
```

> 2. If the same ids having same `timestamp` but the any of column having null(`yob` and `gender`), that time, want to merge the both `id` as single
>    record without null. below I have pasted the data frame and desired
>    output.

Now the above `df_most_recent` contains one or more rows having the same most recent timestamp per `id`, you can group by `id` to merge the values of the other columns like this:

```
result = df_most_recent.groupBy("id").agg(
     *[F.collect_set(c)[0].alias(c) for c in df.columns if c!='id']
     # or *[F.first(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c!='id']
)

result.show()
#+-----+----+------+-------+-------------------+
#|id   |yob |gender|country|timestamp          |
#+-----+----+------+-------+-------------------+
#|5cddf|2010|M     |ED     |2021-09-09 12:00:00|
#|9297d|1999|M     |GF     |2021-10-18 07:00:00|
#|9298e|1990|null  |GF     |2021-10-18 07:00:00|
#|c3882|1975|M     |BD     |2021-11-27 05:00:00|
#|e5882|null|M     |AD     |2021-10-22 13:10:00|
#+-----+----+------+-------+-------------------+
```